# How would the C++11 regex library be implemented?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

What path are the current C++ compilers taking to implement the C++11 regular expressions library?

As I understand it, generating code which implements a deterministic finite state machine recognising a particular regular expression is the easiest way to do it but, presumably, that would imply either that the compiler itself would have to parse function calls to the library in a non-standard way (i.e. by implementing them directly) or that some kind of polymorphic trickery is at play within the library code itself (the kind of thing that I don't *think* is possible in C++).

Are they using some alternative, smarter pure C++ method? Seems like it would be complicated!

Comment: This belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com, possibly.

Comment: Compliers don't implement regexes. The programmers of the standard library do.

Comment: Well, yes, that's why I was asking because it's one of those things that *could* be more easily implemented if the compiler *did* handle them directly.

Comment: Because you could create code for a DFA equivalent to the regexp and insert it inline into the source (a la lexer generators) which you can't do if it's implemented within the library proper.

Comment: Oh never mind, the guy who just asked me why it would be easier deleted his comment -_-

Comment: @Elliott: std::regex was based on boost::regex, which does not depend on any really nonstandard trickery.

Comment: "*Because you could create code for a DFA equivalent to the regexp and insert it inline into the source (a la lexer generators) which you can't do if it's implemented within the library proper.*" That would require, as a first step, having access to the regular expression string at compile time. `std::regex` does *not* require the use of literals as regular expression strings. So what you're suggesting cannot happen.

Comment: Actually, yeah, I hadn't thought of that. Good point. :)